# Input Validation for Vectors C++

Tags: c++, validation, vector

I'm having a problem with the input validation of my do-while loop. My do-while loop only validates every other input

Here's an example:

```
Please Enter Grade 1: 101 (It does not accept input) 

Invalid Rage. Please Enter Range 0-100.
Please Enter Grade 1: 101 (It accapts this input)

Please Enter Grade 2: 101 (It does not accept input) 

Invalid Rage. Please Enter Range 0-100.
Please Enter Grade 2: 101 (It accapts this input)
```

Here's My Code:

```
for(vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  {
    do
    {
         cout << "Please Enter Grade "<< i + 1 <<": " << flush;
            cin >> gradesVector[i];
        }
        while(gradesVector[i] < 0.0 && gradesVector[i] > 100.0);
        { 
            cout << "Invalid Rage. Please Enter Range 0-100:\n";
                cout << "Please Enter Grade "<< i + 1 <<": " << flush;
                    cin >> gradesVector[i];
         }   
}
```

Comment: Why have two loops?

Comment: I'm fairly new with c++ and i  now see that's the wrong way to go about it

Comment: There are many ways to do things. I provided a solution which in its core didn't change much of the essence of your first approach, which wasn't bad. Don't be too hard on yourself. C++, programming, anything is just practice and practice. The more you do, the more you improve. So chill and be happy that you understand why this works now.

Comment: Your new approach will terminate your program if you add a wrong value. Is that what you really want? And it should say gradesVector[i] and your for loop needs braces...

Comment: i updated the question to show exactly what i'm trying to do

Comment: Could you upvote/mark as correct? We helped you fix your question, but now your edit id a complete different question. We can help you answer it, but you should make a new one for that.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
int main() {
   vector<double> gradesVector(15);
   for(vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
       do {
            cout << "Please Enter Grade "<< i + 1 <<": " << flush;
            cin >> gradesVector[i];
       } while(gradesVector[i] < 0.0 || gradesVector[i] > 100.0);
   }
}
```

Comment: when i run the code i don't receive a compiler error but now there's no output

Comment: Try it now. This is where the do while now comes in handy!

Comment: Your `do..while` condition is the wrong way around (though, granted, the OP had this wrong as well). It will continue to request a grade while it's *valid* rather than invalid. Let me fix that for ya :-)

Comment: ok the code is running now but there's still no input validation. I entered -1, 120, and 'A' to check if it would accept it and it did

Comment: @Tayvion, this code won't catch invalid duubles (like `A`), that will need you to check the actual `cin >> blah` bit (and probably `cin.ignore` to the end of line). What it *will* catch is valid doubles outside the range.

Comment: Oops...thanks a bunch @paxdiablo...copy and paste. A programmer's best friend and enemy.

Comment: @paxdiablo...you're clearly an insomniac Julian Assange :D

Comment: Yep, paxdiablo fixed that for us. Is it working now?

Comment: its not still not validating input

Answer (score 0):

The statement `while(gradesVector > 0.0 && gradesVector <= 100.0)` is trying to check if the entire vector is greater than 0 or less than 100, which doesn't really make sense.  You want to do something like `while(gradesVector[i] > 0.0 && gradesVector[i] <= 100.0)` (just make sure `i` is in the correct scope).

Edit: just get rid of the do-while loop and only use a for-loop.  Inside the for-loop, add an if-statement: `if(gradesVector[i] > 0.0 && gradesVector[i] <= 100.0)`.  If the validation fails, use a `break` statement to exit the for-loop.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error                                                         'main.cpp:36:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    while(gradesVector[i] > 0.0 && gradesVector[i] <= 100.0)
                       ^
main.cpp:36:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    while(gradesVector[i] > 0.0 && gradesVector[i] <= 100.0)'

Comment: You're getting that error because the while-loop condition is outside the for-loop.  Also, @user54264611634646244 is right, you don't need two loops.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Zexus it's still allowing to enter numbers less than 0.0 and numbers greater than 100.0